# Can a program continue to work on an opened file after it is moved by another program?

Tags: files, filesystems, inode

When a program opens a file, and another program moves the file so that it has a different pathname/filename, **can** the first program still  work on the file, for example, modify the file's content or attributes and save changes to the file?

I guess yes.

- When a file is moved, it has a different pathname/filename, but it still has the same inode and data blocks.
- When a program opens a file, the pathname/filename of the file is used to look up its inode and data blocks, and the program holds directly or indirectly the pointers to the  data structures of the inode and data blocks of the file. I am not sure if the pathname/filename is still useful after the lookup.

If the answer is yes, what  behaviours are **expected** from programs, suppose you are to create such programs?

- shall they silently work on the moved file,
- shall they notify the user of the moving and ask if they want to continue to work on the moved file?

I often keep   files open in some programs (emacs, some pdf software) as long as possible, long enough that I may likely use other programs (`mv`) to move/rename them at some point in the mean time. Emacs warns me about the fies having been moved, and I don't know if Emacs can continue to work on the moved file, so I usually have to close the buffer and reopen the moved file in a new buffer, which is inconvenient IMO.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure. At least not directly.

Comment: @Tim, the file will have same inode if move in the same filesystem. If move to another filesystem the things become bit odd.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, well, you can't _move_ a file to another filesystem per se. It needs to be done by creating a new file and copying the data. Which kinda tells what happens, the new file is an independent one, with no connection to the old one.

Comment: @ilkkachu users using `mv` or other such tools can’t be expected to always be aware of the distinction.

Comment: @StephenKitt, sure, but as long as we're talking between 5k+ unix.se users...

Comment: There's no "standard behaviour expected" from programs. An editor may only care about the file when reading it and when saving it. There was (is, as at least _I_'m still using it) a library to render djvu files (used by a lot of document viewers), which would open, read some data and CLOSE the file each time it was asked to render a page. IIRC there even was a question here why the "opened" djvu file didn't appear in `lsof`.

Comment: As per the comment from @mosvy.   Note that having a file "loaded" into an application is _not_ the same as having the file "open".  An application _could_ open a file, read all the data into a buffer, then close the file and work on the in-memory data.  And you wouldn't necessarily know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

[How do open files behave on linux systems?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7707/86440) provides some relevant background.

> **can** the first program still work on the file, for example, modify the file's content or attributes and save changes to the file?

As long as the first program keeps its file descriptor open, it can continue making changes to the file using any system call or library function which uses the file descriptor. If the file was moved to another directory in the same file system, those changes will apply to the “new” file; if it was moved to another file system, the changes will ultimately be lost, unless another directory entry points to the same inode.

> When a file is moved, it has a different pathname/filename, but it still has the same inode and data blocks.

If it’s moved within the same file system, yes.

> When a program opens a file, the pathname/filename of the file is used to look up its inode and data blocks, and the program holds directly or indirectly the pointers to the data structures of the inode and data blocks of the file. I am not sure if the pathname/filename is still useful after the lookup.

Yes, with help from the kernel: the program has a file descriptor, which points to a file description maintained by the kernel. The file name is then irrelevant.

> If the answer is yes, what behaviours are **expected** from programs, suppose you are to create such programs?

Nothing is *expected*. Some programs open a file and keep the returned file descriptor for the duration of their operations on the file, including writing updates to the file. Others open a file, keep the returned file descriptor, but use the more involved write-rename pattern to write to the file; this includes Emacs. Emacs in addition watches for external changes to the files it has opened, and warns about any such change.

Ultimately, they’re *your* files, it’s up to you to keep track of what you’re doing with them. Some programs will go out of their way to help you avoid losing data, others won’t.

Comment: Thanks. 1) What is the meaning of " write-rename pattern"? 2) If a program  continues to work on an opened file that has been moved, isn't it convenient for its users?

Comment: 1. It’s a common idiom used on POSIX systems to attempt to minimise the risk of losing data on crashes: when a file is saved, the program writes all its content to a new file, calls `fsync()`, then renames the file over the old one, so that the user ends up with either the old content, or the new content, but not a mix (or nothing). 2. It’s inconvenient, yes, but the user is supposed to be aware that they moved the file. I agree that Emacs-style features are helpful, but nothing *requires* them (but perhaps that would be a useful enhancement to desktop environment guidelines).

Comment: See [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/351422/) for background on the idiom in question.

Answer (score 2):

> can the first program still work on the file, for example, modify the file's content or attributes and save changes to the file?

Yep.

> When a file is moved, it has a different pathname/filename, but it still has the same inode and data blocks.

Yep.

> When a program opens a file, the pathname/filename of the file is used to look up its inode and data blocks, and the program holds directly or indirectly the pointers to the data structures of the inode and data blocks of the file.

Yep. Pretty much the same if you remove the file, though in that case its harder to save any modifications.

> I am not sure if the pathname/filename is still useful after the lookup.

I'm not sure what you mean. I suppose it depends on what one finds useful: if you do the same path lookup again, you might get another file, like in the case here.

Emacs probably thinks it's useful for the user to know if the file was modified while being edited. It has to do something to detect that, either poll the path or use `inotify` or such. Some other editors don't bother.

I don't think there's a "must" here, different programs do what their authors have deemed useful.

FWIW, it comes to mind that editors also vary on how they deal with backup files and if they create the new version of a file as a new inode, or just overwrite the old one. Emacs is probably configurable in this...

Answer (score 1):

> what behaviours are expected from programs

It may help to understand that a program receives no kind of automatic notification that a file that it has open has been renamed.  The file, as you guessed, remains unchanged by a move.  It hasn't changed; the *directory* holding its name changed.  That's also why *directory* permissions, not permissions on the file, govern whether a file can be deleted (or created).

A program can use various techniques to be notified when directories are modified.  Most don't, though, so the "expected" behavior would be silence.

Answer (score 1):

> When a program opens a file, the pathname/filename of the file is used
>   to look up its inode and data blocks,

But the program only gets the file descriptor, not the inode. The inode is for the filesystem internal.

vim tells me this - it even is an error in red:

```
E211: File "test" no longer available
```

even if i just *renamed* it -- by moving. There is no renaming in this concept. A file is many things, but it is the basic unit for practical purposes. It is an error, even though I can just `:w` again, as I would anyway.

There is also:

```
W11: Warning: File "test" has changed since editing started
```

where only contents are concerned.

`vi` seems silent.